# gather() function in r is not finding my columns when they exist

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that details the count of both names that were longer than 5 letters and names that were shorter than 5 letters from the library `babynames`, which I got from `install.packages("babynames")` then `library(babynames)`.

After some filtering and `ifelse` with `str_length(name)`, I created a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
sum_greaterthan5.sum     sum_lessthan5.sum     total_n_names.total_names
2109449                  1436852               3546301
```

I would like to gather the data so I can have one variable/column be the numeric values which represent how many babies were named names longer than 5 letters, and so on...

```
criteria                    count
sum_greaterthan5.sum        2109449                  
sum_lessthan5.sum           1436852               
total_n_names.total_names   3546301
```

However, the `gather` function is not reading my columns properly:

```
> df_5letters <- df %>%
+   gather(key=criteria, value = count, c('sum_greaterthan5.sum', 'sum_lessthan5.sum', 'total_n_names.sum') )

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `sum_greaterthan5.sum` doesn't exist.
```

I tried using column indexing and I got a type related error. Are there other functions out there that I can use in place of `gather`, or another way I can modify my `gather` function?

Below is my code that I ran up to this point:

```
babynames_2017_length_5 <- babynames_2017 %>%
  mutate(five_letters = ifelse(str_length(name)>5,1,0)) %>%
  filter(five_letters == 1) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(n))

babynames_2017_less_5 <- babynames_2017 %>%
  mutate(five_letters = ifelse(str_length(name)>5,1,0)) %>%
  filter(five_letters == 0) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(n))

df <- tibble(
  sum_greaterthan5 = babynames_2017_length_5,
  sum_lessthan5 = babynames_2017_less_5,
  total_n_names = total_n # total_n was a variable that I got from a previous dataframe that I did a sum aggregation on with:
# total_n <- babynames_startwvowels[1,1]
)
```

Comment: The code that generates `df` appears to have different column names to what you were expecting? You have `sum_greaterthan5` not `sum_greaterthan5.sum`, `sum_lessthan5` not `sum_lessthan5.sum`, _etc_.

Answer (score 1):

`babynames_2017_length_5` and `babynames_2017_less_5` is a dataframe and when you are using it in `tibble(..)` you are making a nested dataframe hence `gather` cannot find the column.

Extract the column from the dataframes and it should work fine.

```
df <- tibble(
  sum_greaterthan5 = babynames_2017_length_5$sum,
  sum_lessthan5 = babynames_2017_less_5$sum,
  total_n_names = total_n 
)
```

Moreover, instead of creating two separate dataframes combining them and then using `gather`/`pivot_longer` you could do :

```
babynames %>%
  group_by(five_letters = ifelse(str_length(name)>5, 
                          'sum_greaterthan5', 'sum_lessthan5')) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(n))
```